# Concatenate uncommon literals of 2 strings leaving common literals in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two strings like I shown below,

```
var_1=('class="input {{#if Required}}required{{/if}}"')
var_2=('class="input {{#if emailRequired}}required{{/if}}{{#if contactPointRequired}}required{{/if}}"')
```

and my expected result is

```
'class="input {{#if Required}}{{#if emailRequired}}required{{/if}}{{#if contactPointRequired}}required{{/if}}"'.
```

I mean to say,I want the new string which has elements common in both strings along with the difference of a two strings.

How do I achieve this in python 2.7?

Comment: Your expected result is just the second string.  This doesn't match your description.

Comment: @augurar No it's not just the second string. Look at  `{{#if Required}}{{#if emailRequired}}`  part.

Comment: Ah, missed that.  Still, your description does not explain the operation you want to perform.  It seems like you want to parse the string to tokens of some kind, and then perform some kind of merge on the tokens?  What is the required property the result must satisfy?

Comment: Okay, Here I go.

Those are the class& its value from different files. I want to show the diff of those two elements with different colors and that's why I wanted a string which can give me both the difference of a element along with the common elements. 
If there are differences I want to print/add  it side by side ,or if there are no differences  print/add the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the following approach:

1. (Optional) Split the strings into meaningful tokens
2. Create a [`difflib.SequenceMatcher`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher) for the strings or lists of tokens.
3. Format the output as desired.

Crude example:

```
s1 = 'class="input {{#if Required}}required{{/if}}"'
s2 = 'class="input {{#if emailRequired}}required{{/if}}{{#if contactPointRequired}}required{{/if}}"'

# 0. Split strings into meaningful parts
# In this case I am using a crude regex to detect token boundaries
# Remember, this step is optional

import re
pat = re.compile(r'(\=+|\"+| |\{+|\}+)')
a = pat.split(s1)
b = pat.split(s2)

# 1. Create SequenceMatcher

from difflib import SequenceMatcher
matcher = SequenceMatcher(a=a, b=b, autojunk=False)

# 2. Format output
# Here I am using ANSI escape codes to colorize the output

GREEN='\033[92m'
RED='\033[91m'
ENDC='\033[0m'
line = []
for op, ai, aj, bi, bj in matcher.get_opcodes():
    if op == 'equal':
        line.extend(a[ai:aj])
    else:
        if aj > ai:
            line.append(RED)
            line.extend(a[ai:aj])
            line.append(ENDC)
        if bj > bi:
            line.append(GREEN)
            line.extend(b[bi:bj])
            line.append(ENDC)

print(''.join(line))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This reduced lot of my work. :)

Can you please explain in brief about what have you done?Thank you again :)

Comment: The core functionality comes from `SequenceMatcher.get_opcodes()`, which returns a list of operations to transform the first sequence into the second by inserting, deleting, or replacing pieces of the sequence.  We can use this information to find the differences in the two strings, combine them into one, etc.